# Java, how to create new directory in remote host.

Tags: java, android, directory, host, mkdirs

I'm working on Android app.
how can i create a new directory in a remote host in java?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
String newFolder = "http://www.mysite.it/public/newfolder";
File outFile = new File(newFolder); 
if(!outFile.exists()){   
  boolean b = outFile.mkdirs();
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: A URL path element is not a directory.

Comment: You need to send an HTTP request to server-side code that is willing to do that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can not be done this way. You need to send a command to your server and create the directory from your server.

Then you can send an acknowledgement back to your client

Comment: Yes if you use PHP server side you have to do the server part in PHP. A problem you will get is that anyone also can make a file through your PHP api if you do not program it securely.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: The folder is remote.
When using File you are accessing the local file system.
To connection to a remote host, you will need a URLConnection, HTTPUrlConnection or sockets.
So the file constructed using your string won't represent a valid file.
Creating folders on a remote host require the use of protocols such as ssh or ftp.
As an example:

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/index.html");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
```

would open a ftp - connection to host mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca requesting a file named index.html.

command - line ftp clients can send commands for creating folders to the remote host, e.g.

ftp anonoumos@somehost.com
 # mkdir folderName
so you would have to send this command to your ftp host. For ssh it's basically the same procedure.

Both requires a basic client, though.
There are existing solutions around in the Java World, but I don't know of any for Android.
So while uploading a file to a host via ftp is pretty straight forward, (take a look at this example http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/upload-files-to-ftp-server-using-urlconnection-class), sending commands via ftp seems to be a lot more complicated task.
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient e.g. supports sending commands via it's doCommand - method, but I don't know if you get it to work on android.